# 5 tables in 1 pivot table relationship

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013, excel-pivot

I have 5 tables (each table has a Date column)
I want to make a relationship between all the dates of all the tables in the pivot table to do some data analysis.

But unfortunately, the relationship is between 2 columns only
However, i tried to make 1 sheet as the primary sheet, and make relationship with others, but it pops out with error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using =SUMIF() and inserting the desired date values manually for the comparison.
It will be difficult to pivot on multiple tables with non-unique keys to summarize on (ie date values aren't unique so how does each piece of data fit together)
You could also build pivot tables for each table first, then combine all of those together

Comment: you mentioned: create pivot tables then combine all? is that possible?